# URL alias with multi-lingual site access doesnt work

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, redirection, uri

i have two systems, one live system and a local one, which are almost the same configured.

i have a node which is in english (/testEN) and basic translated in german(/testDE). if i call on my local system **localhost/testEN** the page changes its language to english and it goes to the node. if i call **localhost/testDE** the page changes to german and redirects to the german node.

on the live system i need to write before the URL the siteaccess e.g. www.examplepage.de/**en/testEN** or www.examplepage.de/**de/testDE**.

if i just call www.examplepage.de/testDE the site gives a **404 PAGE NOT FOUND**.

From where comes this diffrence? why doesnt drupal recognize the URL alias with the node translation like in my local system? 
is there any setting i didnt see?

any solution would be nice.

Comment: And it works if you go to: www.examplepage.de/de/testDE ?

Comment: yes this works.

Comment: are you using cpanel for the live site?

Comment: Have you checked `/admin/config/regional/language/detection` ? Those settings should be the same for both enviroments.

Comment: i found it by accident. there was the same settings but it was only available after update.php. nevermind thank you guys